# TinyMce p and br replaced with \r\n

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

With the below init config , the **p** and **br** tag is replaced with \r\n in the output of the editor. tried several config config none seems to be working . 
I was trying to  create addition visual editor in WordPress , is there any predifed wp tinymce config that can be applied directly , and my editor is also missing some of the buttons that i have created in the primary wp editor .

```
 tinymce.init({


    remove_linebreaks : false,
    forced_root_block : 'p', 
    mode : "specific_textareas",
    apply_source_formatting : 'true',

    formats: {
        bold : {inline : 'b' },
        italic : {inline : 'i' }
    }, 
     ,
    selector: 'textarea.textarea_ct', 
    setup: function (editor) {
        editor.on('change', function () {

            tinymce.triggerSave();

        })
    },
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install the suggested plug-in, though. Just add this mini plugin and you're set:

```html
<?php
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) OR exit;
/* Plugin Name: TinyMCE break instead of paragraph */
function mytheme_tinymce_settings( $tinymce_init_settings ) {
    $tinymce_init_settings['forced_root_block'] = false;
    return $tinymce_init_settings;
}
add_filter( 'tiny_mce_before_init', 'mytheme_tinymce_settings' );
```

Now when you press enter, 
 tag will be inserted instead of creating new paragraph. But beware, if you create two consecutive newlines, the text will still be split to paragraph as a result of [

```html
remove_filter ( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter ( 'the_content', 'add_newlines_to_post_content' );
function add_newlines_to_post_content( $content ) {
    return nl2br( $content );
}
```

][1](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) filter applied to your post content. You need to remove this filter first and create a new filter that will replace all newlines with 
 tags. Add something like this to your functions.php to display the 
 tags in your template:

Comment: But there should be a option to get the content without /r/n .

Comment: @RajaMohammed - But in editor is not possible all tags. so, you can create the own code.

Comment: in my case i dont need that filtes , i have added `wpautop($text_content)` to create active `<p>` tags but it fails to create line breaks `<br>`

Comment: @RajaMohammed - once you try to test with plugin. Plugin Remove Empty P Tag: https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-empty-p-tag/ and Empty P Tag: https://wordpress.org/plugins/empty-p-tag/

Comment: i would appreciate your help . My output doesnot add   unnecessary p or br tag , i just want the \r\n to be a valid line breaks the problem with nl2br is it adds br tag at the end of list items aswell.  

i use wpautop($output) it chages the \r\n to p tags but the additional line breaks are stripped off .